Is there an upper bound on two-qubit fidelity improvements?
The higher the two-qubit fidelity, the lower the overhead for quantum error correction. This is especially preferable due to the fact that cheap QRAM would be useful for practical applications, QRAM is expensive due to error correction, and classical RAM doesn't need error correction.
Is there an upper bound on how much two-qubit fidelities can be improved? Is there some type of no-go theorem that says, for example, "The highest 2 qubit fidelity you can get from transmons is X?". If so, what is it? The highest prediction I could find is $10^{-6}$ for Majorana qubits. I'm not aware of a lower prediction.

If we generally improve two-qubit gate fidelities across the board, it seems like QRAM with sufficiently low logical error rates will be relatively still as expensive. Is the outlook on this question to make physical error rates sufficiently low that QRAM needs no error correction?

It is not. I only gave QRAM as an example of why it's good to have low fidelities. Whether or not QRAM is practical with low fideltities is an independent matter.
